# OCaml mutable variant types

Tags: types, ocaml, immutability, mutable, mutability

[Caml Light manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/distrib/caml-light-0.74//cl74refman.pdf) mentions mutable variant types on page 37:

```
type foo = A of mutable int
         | B of mutable int * int
```

But this extension doesn't seem to be a part of OCaml, or is it?
Am I right that the only way to define a mutable variant type in OCaml is to use mutable records or arrays?

```
(* with records *)
type a = {mutable a: int}
and b = {mutable b1: int; mutable b2: int}
and foo = A of a
        | B of b

(* with arrays *)
type foo = A of int array
         | B of int array
```

**Edit:** Thanks @gasche suggesting using refs, which are a shortcut for mutable record:

```
type foo = A of int ref 
         | B of int ref * int ref
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, mutable variants were dropped in the transition between Caml Light and OCaml, in part because the syntax to manipulate them was so awkward (pattern-matching on a mutable field would make the pattern identifier a lvalue, yumm...).

The current ways to express mutability are through mutable record fields (which have a proper field mutation syntax), or references `int ref` (which are defined as one-field mutable records).

Answer (score 2):

You could use refs as a shorthand.

Check 2.2  Mutable storage and side effects from http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/u3-ocaml/ocaml-core.html